# 'clickable' drop down menu css

Tags: php, jquery

Hello I'm just trying to figure out the concept of this example menu

http://www.cdrking.com

is it even a drop down menu at all? Sorry for my vague question, I'm still confused between php and javascript implementation. I'm trying to make something like their category menu so the right side will update as clicked.

Any ideas?

Comment: What menu do you mean? The 'Browse by product' menu? You could use the jQuery UI accordeon for that.

Comment: There's a trick using CSS3 that replaces `:hover` with `:active` and adds a long transition to keep it from "snapping" back after the click. However, I can't recommend it because of the lack of broad CSS3 transition support.

Comment: @Mikey: It's a shame you haven't posted it as an answer

Comment: @Truth: I first wanted to be sure what OP meant with "category menu", but appearently my guess was right?

Comment: It's a mix of both but I'm starting with the menu first before the browsing by product. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you want to use jquery for that. You can probably find a plug-in already written if you do a search for something like "jquery menu" or "jquery dropdown". You'll find a ton of options.

The difference between php and javascript is, in the most basic answer: PHP uses data to make changes before the page loads, and to interact with the server/other pages. Javascript can make changes to a page even after it loads but does not interact with the server or other pages. So any kind of sliding or animated elements are likely to be javascript or jquery (or flash or css3 but that is something else entirely). Someone else can probably explain it more in depth or more technically correct, but I wanted to keep it basic as it sounds like you are just getting started.

Comment: thank you for @Digital Brent for the clear explanation for my confused mind :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want an 'Accordion' menu, like this - http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/javascript-accordion/

Comment: Thanks :) this is what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 0):

To implement it instead of a hover menu, change your code:

```
:hover -> .clicked
```

And use jQuery or vanilla JS to toggle the class on the clicked elements:

```
$('#menu li').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery ui to put together a beautiful accordion menu.  it actually makes that one look a little silly by comparison

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Here it is on JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nMNaf/